# HTML Layout with float configuration - aligning to middle

Tags: html, css

I have a floating layout in HTML and I want to place boxes both at the beginning, ending and also in the middle.

Here is my snippet:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
}

.tray {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.tray-top,
.tray-bottom {
  height: 48px;
  line-height:48px;
  clear: both;
}

.tray-left,
.tray-right {
  width: 48px;
  height: calc(100% - 96px);
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.tray-right {
  float: right;
}

.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
}

.tray-top .button,
.tray-bottom .button {
  max-width: 33%;
}

.tray-left .button,
.tray-right .button {
  max-height: 33%;
}

.tray-top .button.begin,
.tray-bottom .button.begin {
  float: left;
}

.tray-top .button.middle,
.tray-bottom .button.middle {
  float: left;
}

.tray-top .button.end,
.tray-bottom .button.end {
  float: right;
}

.button.middle {
}


.tray-left .button.end,
.tray-right .button.end {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <div class="tray tray-top">
  <div class="button begin">1</div>
  <div class="button middle">2</div>
  <div class="button end">3</div>
 </div>
    <div class="tray tray-left">
  <div class="button begin">4</div>
  <div class="button middle">5</div>
  <div class="button end">6</div>
 </div>
    <div class="tray tray-right">
  <div class="button begin">7</div>
  <div class="button middle">8</div>
  <div class="button end">9</div>
 </div>
    <div class="tray tray-bottom">
  <div class="button begin">10</div>
  <div class="button middle">11</div>
  <div class="button end">12</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I make (please see it in Full page):

- Box2 and Box11 to go into middle (while keeping box3 and box12 at the end)?
- Box5 and Box8 to go into middle vertically?
- <s>Box6 and Box9 to go to the end vertically?</s>

I don't want to stick to this layout but I would like to keep the widest support for all the browsers (including IE11 too).

Please note that #root has 80% width and height. It only means #root's size != body's size (so absolute positioning and `left: 50%` is not a way to go).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add some flexbox for this. It would be difficult to do it with only float and probably not good to use positionning:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 85%;
  width: 85%;
}

.tray {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.tray-top,
.tray-bottom {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  clear: both;
}

.tray-left,
.tray-right {
  width: 48px;
  height: calc(100% - 96px);
  float: left;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.tray-right {
  float: right;
}

.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.begin {
 float:left;
}
.end {
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="tray tray-top">
    <div class="button begin">1</div>
    <div class="button middle">2</div>
    <div class="button end">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-left">
    <div class="button begin">4</div>
    <div class="button middle">5</div>
    <div class="button end">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-right">
    <div class="button begin">7</div>
    <div class="button middle">8</div>
    <div class="button end">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-bottom">
    <div class="button begin">10</div>
    <div class="button middle">11</div>
    <div class="button end">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves my issue but I'm not sure if this is the most sophisticated solution for this problem:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
}

.tray {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.tray-top,
.tray-bottom {
  height: 48px;
  line-height:48px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
}

.tray-left,
.tray-right {
  width: 48px;
  height: calc(100% - 96px);
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.tray-right {
  float: right;
}

.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
}

.tray-top .button,
.tray-bottom .button {
  max-width: 33%;
}

.tray-left .button,
.tray-right .button {
  max-height: 33%;
}

.tray-top .button.begin,
.tray-bottom .button.begin {
  float: left;
}

.tray-top .button.middle,
.tray-bottom .button.middle {
  float: left;
}

.tray-top .button.end,
.tray-bottom .button.end {
  float: right;
}

.button.middle {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.tray-left .button.end,
.tray-right .button.end {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <div class="tray tray-top">
  <div class="button begin">1</div>
  <div class="button middle">2</div>
  <div class="button end">3</div>
 </div>
    <div class="tray tray-left">
  <div class="button begin">4</div>
  <div class="button middle">5</div>
  <div class="button end">6</div>
 </div>
    <div class="tray tray-right">
  <div class="button begin">7</div>
  <div class="button middle">8</div>
  <div class="button end">9</div>
 </div>
    <div class="tray tray-bottom">
  <div class="button begin">10</div>
  <div class="button middle">11</div>
  <div class="button end">12</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I had to make the middle boxes `position: absolute` and their parents to `position: relative` then I'm able to change their position within their parents.